# How to find this Total curvature for this surface? (Gauss - Bonnet thm)

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I'm triying to find the $\int\int_D K ds$ ($K$ is a Gaussian curvature of the $S$) The conditions like the below.

Here the $D = \{(x,y) \vert x^2 + y^2 \leq 1, (x,y)\in S\}$

Let the sphere  $T : (2cosusinv, 2sinusinv, 2cosu)$ ,$(0 \leq u \leq 2\pi, 0 \leq v \leq \pi)$

There is a surface $S : z= f(x,y)$ which is $S$ and $T$ are orthogonal each other. The intersection line of the two surfaces is $X(u, \frac{\pi}{6})$

So, my solution is  If we use Gauss- Bonnet, we can easily find the  $\int_\alpha k_g ds$  (This case curve $\alpha$ is $\partial D$(or $X(u,\frac{\pi}{6}$))

First $\int\int_D K ds$ + $\int_\alpha  k_g ds = 2\pi$.

Next step is just finding the $\int_\alpha  k_g ds$
[image]

The curve $\alpha$ is a circle its radius "$1$"(c.f. the picture 1.)  Hence curvature is $1$

[image]

So, $kg = <B,U_S>= cos(\pi - \theta) = -$ $\frac{1}{2}$ (Here the $B$ is a binormal vector of the curve $\alpha$) (c.f. the picture 2)

Hence $\int_\alpha  k_g ds $ = $-$$\pi$. My answer is  $\int\int_D K ds$ $ = 3\pi$.

But the answer is $\int\int_D K ds$ $ = \pi$ claiming  $\int_\alpha  k_g ds = \pi $

What did I wrong?

Comment: This is very confusing. What precisely is the surface to which you are applying Gauss-Bonnet? You have random letters everywhere. What is $S$? You write $(x,y)\in S$, which makes no sense. Please clarify exactly what $D$ is and why the boundary curve is oriented clockwise instead of counterclockwise.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Sorry for late reply. I've got my mistake from your comment. And now solved it  thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radius of sphere is 2; spherical cap height is 1 ;

GB Theorem, consider tangential radius of curvature.

$$ \int K dS+ \int k_g ds = \int K dS+ \int  ds/R_g = 2 \pi$$

The first term is Integral Curvature
$$= 2 \pi- \dfrac{s_{boundary}}{Rg} = 2 \pi- 2 \sqrt 3  \pi/(2 \sqrt 3)= \pi$$

[image]

Alternately area of yellow spherical cap you are interested directly $ = \pi$ and the Integral curvature is $=1\cdot \pi$

Please note !

First $\int k_g ds$ should be computed. Its sign has a significance in GB theorem.

The same symbol $s$ should not be used for arc length and Area. The latter symbol, for surface area is $S.$